# Why does this fread segfault

Tags: c, stdio

I have tried many things to fix this segfault issue, I'm not sure whats happening wrong because from my understanding, the fread line should not segfault

```
// ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./recover file");
        return 1;
    }

    char* recover = argv[1];
    // open input file
    FILE * raw_file = fopen(recover, "r");
    if (raw_file == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open %s.\n", recover);
        return 2;
    }

    //somehow read the file

    int counter = 1;
    char file[2];
    sprintf(file,"%03i.jpg",counter);

    int buffer[512];

    //read file and put into buffer
    int*bf = malloc(sizeof(int));
    fread(bf, sizeof(int), 1, raw_file);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you smashed you stack in this block prior to your `fread`

```
char file[2];
sprintf(file,"%03i.jpg",counter);
```

`file` is to small to hold the number of characters you are formatting into it.

Comment: How do I fix this? Do I increase the array to be larger?

Comment: Yes, the buffer need to be at least one character larger than the largest possible string (to account for the null terminator). In this case it looks like that largest string is 7 so you would need a size of 8.

Comment: Its working now, however I dont understand why its the case, and why the segfault occured at the fread

Comment: Once your stack is corrupted, behavior can be very unpredictable. You probably overwrite the file handle with parts of the string your where formatting, which caused `fread` to try to interpret text as a pointer to internal state.